# Can you suggest a method to generate random sample from following PDF?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, monte-carlo

‎Let‎ ${‎‎\bf{\alpha}}=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m)$ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎\textbf{b}=(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m, b_{m+1}).$ I intend ‎to ‎generate ‎sample ‎from PDF
$$
g(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m)=Const. ‎\frac{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i)^{m+1}}{\prod_{j=1}^{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_ic_i+d_j)^{a_j}}‎‎\times f_{Dirichlet}({\bf{\alpha}}) , ‎~~~\alpha_i, c_i, d_j, ‎a_j>0‎
$$
where ‎$‎f_{Dirichlet}‎$ ‎is ‎the ‎PDF ‎of ‎Dirichlet ‎Type-II ‎distribution, i.e.‎
$$
‎f_{Dirichlet}({\bf{\alpha}})=‎\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}b_i) \prod_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i^{b_i-1}}{\prod_{i=1}^{m+1}\Gamma(b_i)(1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i)^{\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}b_i}}‎~~~b_i>0.
$$
I think the Metropolis-Hastings (MH) algorithm is useful. But I don't  know how to choose a suitable jump distribution for choosing candidate
values. What is your idea?‎

Comment: Shouldn't the normalization constant just be the reciprocal of the prefactor, since $f $ is a pdf? Or is $\alpha $ part of the output, not just a parameter vector?

Comment: OK yeah, I looked up the Dirichlet distribution, which indicates that  $\alpha$ are just parameters. So your prefactor is only dependent on the parameters, so if $f$ is already a pdf then the normalization constant must just cancel out this prefactor. So your pdf, as currently written, is just the Dirichlet pdf.

Comment: Or is it instead that you are randomly sampling $\alpha$ and then independently sampling from the Dirichlet distribution (so the output value is actually $(\alpha,b)$ and $c,d,a$ are fixed)? In that case, do you already have an algorithm for sampling $b$ given $\alpha$? MH might be useful for sampling $\alpha$.

Comment: In my question $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m$ are random variables. $c_i, b_i, d_j$ are positive values and are not unknown.

Comment: $b_1, \ldots, b_{m+1}$ are parameters of Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: OK. Well, suppose for a moment that all but one $\alpha_i$ is frozen. Then the pdf looks like $\frac{(C_1+\alpha_1)^{m+1}}{(c_1 \alpha_1 + C_2)^{a_1}(c_1 \alpha_1+C_3)^{a_2}}$ for auxiliary parameters $C_1,C_2,C_3$ (depending on the other $\alpha_i$). The scaling of this at infinity is $\alpha_1^{m+1-a_1-a_2}$. I assume then that $m+1-a_1-a_2<-1$? If so, then you could initially sample $\alpha$ as an iid vector with that power law distribution as its tail. Then decide something simple in a neighborhood of zero, like a uniform distribution.

Comment: (Cont.)  Then you can use MH to determine whether to accept a new sample for $\alpha$, and then sample $b$ using $f$ given $\alpha$. This might be slow, but at the risk of premature optimization, it might be good to try it before rejecting it in favor of something more complicated.

Comment: $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{m+1}$ are not random variables. So I have not need to generate sample b.

Comment: I see; this is different notation from the Wikipedia article (and really from general use, usually Greek letters are parameters). Your notation is clear now, though. Anyway, in that case my previous idea should still work: take your base distribution to be iid vectors drawn from a mixture of a uniform distribution on a neighborhood of zero and a power law distribution, where the scaling of the power law should match the scaling of your pdf at infinity. Then use MH acceptance-rejection. See how that performs (it might be very bad, since this is quite naive).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can sample from the Dirichlet distribution efficiently, a simple approach would be to make your base rule be sampling independently from the Dirichlet distribution, then use Metropolis-Hastings acceptance/rejection. Call the Dirichlet pdf $d(\cdot;b)$. Then your acceptance probability for the transition $\alpha \to \alpha'$ is the smaller of $1$ and $\frac{g(\alpha')}{g(\alpha)} \frac{d(\alpha;b)}{d(\alpha';b)}$, which is the ratio of the prefactors in front of the Dirichlet pdf.

Comment: I can generate sample from Dirichlet distribution. But your method has low acceptance rate for the transition $\alpha \to \alpha'$.

Comment: @K.Ahmadi If the acceptance probability is low then the prefactor for $\alpha'$ is much less than the prefactor for $\alpha$, which should usually mean that $\alpha'$ is much less likely than $\alpha$. Of course this is still bad, because your decorrelation time will become long this way. Is it possible that your distribution is somewhat sharply peaked? (You have not said what $a,b,c,d$ actually are yet.)

Comment: $\mathbf{a, b, c, d}$ are the parameters of g distribution. They are known and positive.

Comment: @K.Ahmadi I know they are known. But you haven't said what their actual values are. That could be having an impact on the low acceptance rate, since it could mean that the prefactor, when $\alpha$ is Dirichlet distributed, has a high variance. (We want the "residual" factor to have a *low* variance.) If it does have a high variance then ideally we would partially build it into the way that we draw samples.